# Determining the number of Amazon S3 instances

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I determine the number of instances needed for an application that allows users to upload images. If number of users is required use 10,000 and 100,000.

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to the [official S3 documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) . S3 "instances" is a wrong term and if you are meaning "buckets" you lack of knowledge :) There's a per account limitation of 100 buckets but this is meaningless because the size of one bucket is unlimited.